# Is there a Matlab function to convert any data structure to a string?

Tags: matlab

I'm looking for a function in Matlab to use for error messages, like so:

```
error(['Invalid value for someVariable: ' wantedFunction(someVariable)]);
```

I want `wantedFunction` to be able to take both strings, arrays, cell arrays, ideally even structure arrays.

For now, I'm using `num2str`, but that doesn't work for cells. I thought what I want could be done with `sprintf`, but I haven't figured out how. I suppose I could write my own function, but that would be redundant if there already is a way to do this in Matlab. Any ideas?

Comment: Look at my latest edit (toString.m). This is the version to be placed on the file exchange once approved.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, although it's not straightforward. You have to use the `disp` in combination with `evalc`:

```
string = evalc(['disp(someVariable)'])
```

You could cast this into more manageable form:

```
toString = @(var) evalc(['disp(var)']);
```

So, for your example:

```
>> var = {rand(3,1), 'A', struct('test', 5)};
>> error(['Invalid value for var: ' toString(var)])

??? Invalid value for var:     [3x1 double]    'A'    [1x1 struct]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for: the simplest way of doing it. To avoid making a homebrew toString function (be it one line or a full function), I guess one could do: `disp(someVariable); error('... is an invalid value for someVariable');`

Comment: I ended up using the function in your other answer, though :)

Comment: This will not print nestes structures

Comment: @Dims: true. For that, I'll refer to my [FEX contribution](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38566-string-representation-of-any-data-type) that handles the more general case.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such function. I ran into similar problems, so here is a very rudimentary function that I use. Do realize that it is not complete. For example, it does not output fields of a structure in a meaningful way, but that can easily be added. You can treat it as a base implementation and fit it to your needs.

```
function ret = all2str(param)
if isempty(param)
    if iscell(param)
        ret = '(empty cell)';
    elseif isstruct(param);
        ret = '(empty struct)';
    else
        ret = '(empty)';
    end
    return;
end

if ischar(param)
    ret = param;
    return;
end

if isnumeric(param)
    ret = num2str(param);
    return;
end

if iscell(param)
    ret = all2str(param{1});
    for i=2:numel(param)
        ret = [ret ', ' all2str(param{i})];
    end
    return;
end

if isstruct(param)
    ret = '(structure)';
    return;
end
end
```

Comment: Hmmm...I don't seem to have `mall2str`...is that an R2012 issue? Plus: why don't you print the structure by using `fieldnames` etc.? And why don't you print `'[]'` or `'{}'` for empties?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis You don't have have it, because I wrote it for in-house use. It is by no means perfect. As I said in my answer, I do not handle structures. Because I never needed that particular feature ;) But sure, it can be easily implemented. The things I print were just convenient for me.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis ow, there was a typo there. I renamed `mall2str` to `all2str`, but not everywhere.... Thanks

Comment: See my second answer, and tell me what you think.

Comment: Thanks, angainor. Writing a dedicated function is probably the best way of doing this.

Comment: Look at my edit (toString.m). This is the version to be placed on the file exchange once approved.

Answer (score 2):

Come to think of it, I remember doing something a long time ago quite similar to what angainor has done in his answer. I'll post it here for anyone interested in converting arbitrary things to string, and generally having more control over how that conversion is done.

It supports empties, logicals, chars, function handles, numerics, cells, struct (arrays), and user-defined classes (sparse arrays in the next update).

**EDIT:** I've taken this as a template for an update that I ended up placing on the [file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38566-string-representations-for-most-data-types). Feel free to experiment it and modify to suit your needs.

Comment: +1 They start similar, just that I gave up right after the start, while you seem to have pushed it a bit further ;)

Comment: Great! I guess this is the function to use if one wants to do it properly, then.

Comment: Cool! I will gladly use it. You did quite some work on it... Now a function like that finally exists :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks weird, but

```
str = matlab.unittest.diagnostics.ConstraintDiagnostic.getDisplayableString(value)
```

does the job for you instead using that unesthetic `evalc(disp())` approach.