# Java's toString equivalent in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, tostring

Is there any function in Matlab, which can convert to string of any datatype?

No any prints Matlab loves like `1x6 cell` accepted.

It should print all elements of all datatypes like cell arrays, structs, matrices and so on. With no compromise.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this code](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38566-string-representation-of-any-data-type), which is located at [this github repository](https://github.com/rodyo/FEX-toString).

> TOSTRING    produce string representation of any datatype
>
> S = TOSTRING(A) produces a string representation of A, where class(A)
>   can be one of
>
> ```
> double,   single                          
> logical,       
> char,          
> int8,     uint8       
> int16,    uint16 
> int32,    uint32 
> int64,    uint64  
> cell,          
> struct,  
> function_handle, 
> (user-implemented class name)
> ```
>
> The default string represenation is as verbose as possible.  That
>   means the contents of structure fields, cell array   entries, etc. are
>   representated in fully expanded form.
>
> S = TOSTRING(A, 'disp') produces a string representaion that   is
>   identical to what the command 'disp(A)' would produce.
>
> S = TOSTRING(A, 'compact') or S = TOSTRING(A, N) (with N a positive 
>   integer) limits the number of digits displayed in numerical arrays  to
>   either 4 ('compact') or N.

Example:

```
a = struct('someField', uint32(10*rand(2)), 'otherField', {{[]}});
>> S = toString(a)
S =
1x1 struct:       
someField: [9  7]
           [2  2]
otherField: { [] }

>> S = toString(a, 'disp')
S =
someField: [2x2 uint32]
otherField: []
```

If it does not fit what you want, you can try this: [Is there a Matlab function to convert any data structure to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799161/is-there-a-matlab-function-to-convert-any-data-structure-to-a-string)

Comment: [Meta page on why link only answers are bad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers),  See quote: "When someone goes on Stack Overflow, the question "answer" should actually contain an answer. Not just a bunch of directions towards the answer."

Comment: Now do we have to put a tutorial at answers, @scrappedcola? The links I provided are very simple to read and learn... I think it is not so good only replicate information. Besides, sometimes it is better to teach how to fish than only give the fish...

Comment: The point is that a link only answer is useless later on for users if the link "breaks". If you think it's a question that shows no research effort then make  a close vote. If it's worth answering then answer properly. If you find an SO that already answers it then you should flag it as duplicate.

Comment: It will remains being useless if we answer with code that is used by a library referenced by a link that broke... This is subjective/relative... I understand what you are saying, but there are cases in which a reference by itself is enough. I provided two links, one describing what the code do and another with the code itself (github). In this case, I think it is enough. But, as I said, it is subjective. @scrappedcola By the way, I updated the answer with more information.